# How to create convex honeycomb thing?

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender.
Created some thing earlier in Fusion360.
[image]
[image]

Now I need to create it in Blender. What is a right way to make it? (Not import to Blender but create it from scratch).

PS. Its not need to be 100% the same, some differences are allowed

Comment: show what did u try?

Comment: I'm in searching about cutting :) https://i.imgur.com/8OnUcZ3.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could give 2 *Array* modifiers to an hexagon, duplicate this hexagon with its modifiers and shift the duplication to have the hive:

[image]

Apply the modifiers, join the 2 objects, merge by distance to merge the adjacent vertices:

[image]

Create a circle, use it to cut the hive with the *Knife Project* tool:

[image]

Invert the selection and delete the edges:

[image]

Join the circle to the hive, in *Edit* mode extrude the circle, activate the *Auto Merge* and *Split Edges & Faces* option, then select all, press <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will merge the 2 meshes:

[image]

Clean the topology (dissolve the useless vertices with some <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, I haven't done it here), enable the *Proportional Editing* option, select the center and move up (to round you could also use the *Warp* modifier, or the *Surface Deform* modifier, or a *Shrinkwrap*, etc):

[image]

Extrude down to give it thickness, flatten on Z:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, instruction is clear, will try now.



If I want to make bottom side like 'dome', can I extrude first, then use step with _Proportional Editing_?

https://i.imgur.com/qKOvu33.png

Comment: oh ok in that case just extrude and you're good, don't flatten the extrusion

Comment: thanks! btw, what do you think about making 'dome' first (by revolving?) and then cutting out holes with a hexagonal cylinders array?

Comment: it would work as well but there's still the problem of how to cut the hive to make it circular